# Is it possible to call function from a constructor in java

Tags: java

I've tried this:

```
class rectangle{
    rectangle(int a, int b){
        int area(){
            return(a*b);
        }
    }
    rectangle(int c){
        int area(){
            return(c*c);
        }
    }
}
class session1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        rectangle obj=new rectangle();
        System.out.println("The area of rectangle is: "+obj.area(20,10));
        System.out.println("The area of square is: "+obj.area(10));
    }
}
```

It is showing error: ';' expected
        int area(){
                ^
It should have two constructors (with two arguments and one argument) to create objects as rectangle or square and it has a method called area () that returns the area of the corresponding object

Comment: What you are trying isn't calling a method from constructor (which is totally possible) but **defining a method inside a constructor**. And that is not valid java.

Comment: If I define method area outside of the constructor then how I will call it from the constructor?  help me out

Comment: Side note, best practice would dictate starting class names with a capital letter, i.e. `Rectangle` and `Session1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not designing this in a good way :

- name with UpperCaser for `classes` and lowerCaser for attributs/variables
- use different constructors, one for real `Rectangle` and one for `Rectangle` that are `square`

```
class Rectangle{
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public Rectangle(int a, int b){
        this.width=a; this.height=b
    }
    public Rectangle(int c){
       this(c, c);
    }
    public int getArea(){
        return width*height;
    }
}
class session1{
   // two ways of using it
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("The area of rectangle is: "+new Rectangle(20,10).getArea();
        Rectangle obj = new Rectangle(10);
        System.out.println("The area of square is: "+obj.getArea());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class rectangle{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    rectangle(int a, int b){
        this.a=a; this.b=b;
    }
    rectangle(int c){
       this.a = this.b = c;
    }
    int area(){
        return a*b;
    }
}
class session1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("The area of rectangle is: "+new rectangle(20,10).area());
        System.out.println("The area of square is: "+new rectangle(10).area());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, you juste copy/paste the answer I put before editing ;)